# Change a flat collection of data into a nested tree hierarchy in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have created a view that combines multiple foreign key tables.So the fetched data looks something like this:

```
Id    Name    TagId    DepartmentId    Code
1     N1      T1       NULL            NULL
1     N1      T2       NULL            NULL
1     N1      NULL     D1              NULL
1     N1      NULL     NULL            C1
1     N1      NULL     NULL            C2
2     N2      T3       NULL            NULL
2     N2      NULL     D2              NULL
```

Want the result in model format like this:

```
[{
    Id: 1,
    Name: N1,
    TagIds: [T1, T2],
    DepartmentId: D1,
    Codes: [C1, C2]
},
{
    Id: 2,
    Name: N2,
    TagIds: [T3],
    DepartmentId: D2,
    Codes: []
}]
```

What is the most easy and efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually shown us what you've tried, but if you grab your entire view data into an `IEnumerable` into memory, you can use Linq's `GroupBy` to define groups, from which within you can use Linq filtering and projecting to map out the various properties in each Group.

I've assumed `Id and Name` have a 1:1 cardinality, so have used that in a Value Tuple grouping key. The output is projected to an anonymous type.

Your final output requires Json Serialization, but you can find any number of answers on SO to do that:

```
var groups = items.GroupBy(i => (i.Id, i.Name))
     .Select(grp => new 
     {
        grp.Key.Id, 
        grp.Key.Name, 
        TagIds = grp.Where(i => i.TagId != null)
                    .Select(x => x.TagId)
                    .ToArray(),
        DepartmentId = grp.FirstOrDefault(i => i.DepartmentId != null)?.DepartmentId,
        Codes = grp.Where(i => i.Code != null)
                    .Select(x => x.Code)
                    .ToArray(),
    });
```

Test Data Here:

```
var items = new[]{
    new {Id = 1, Name = "N1", TagId = "T1", DepartmentId = (string)null, Code = (string)null},
    new {Id = 1, Name = "N1", TagId = "T2", DepartmentId = (string)null, Code = (string)null},
    new {Id = 1, Name = "N1", TagId = (string)null, DepartmentId = "D1", Code = (string)null},
    new {Id = 1, Name = "N1", TagId = (string)null, DepartmentId = (string)null, Code = "C1"},
    new {Id = 1, Name = "N1", TagId = (string)null, DepartmentId = (string)null, Code = "C2"},
    new {Id = 2, Name = "N2", TagId = "T3", DepartmentId = (string)null, Code = (string)null},
    new {Id = 2, Name = "N2", TagId = (string)null, DepartmentId = "D2", Code = (string)null},
};
```

The output looks like so in LinqPad:

[image: LinqPads Console.Writeline Output of the above]

Comment: I'm curious, how did you convert his sample data into an array? It would be useful to convert sample data quickly when working with LinqPad.

Comment: It's handcrafted, although once you've got one line in place it's easy enough. I guess it would be nice to get a C# equivalent to [SqlFiddle's Text to DDL](http://sqlfiddle.com/) function though - that's super useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using Linq`s `GroupBy` method.
Here is a clean example:

```
var result = items.GroupBy(i => new { i.Id, i.Name })
                  .Select(g => new Result
                  {
                      Id = g.Key.Id,
                      Name = g.Key.Name,
                      TagIds = g.Select(i => i.TagId).ToList(),
                      DepartmentId = g.FirstOrDefault(i => i.DepartmentId != null)?.DepartmentId,
                      Codes = g.Select(i => i.Code).ToList();
                  });
```